# How can I use table layers in torch to create my own network?

Tags: deep-learning, torch, resnet

I get stuck about nn package in torch7, especially its table layers. How can I use its ConcatTable, CAddTable or any other methods to create network below?

[image]

Here I have two branch of my network, one contains 3 convolution layers and another only one layer. I wanted to sum the outputs of my last two convolution layers(sum the output of convolution 4th and convolution 5th), how should write my torch code using nn package.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your branches are implemented correctly:

```
local net = nn.Sequential()
    :add(conv1)
    :add(nn.ConcatTable()
        :add(branch1)
        :add(branch2))
    :add(nn.CAddTable())
```

`nn.CAddTable` is not to be confused with `nn.Sum`. The first one receives a table of tensors and returns the summation of all tensor while the second one receives a single tensor and computes the sum of its elements along the specified dimension.

Comment: Can you please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53907527/use-table-layer-in-torch-to-add-some-branches) post which is somehow similar to this post and help me to overcome it?